# Return 2D char array from function in c++ and print it

Tags: c++, memory-management, malloc, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation

This is my code and I want to return 2D dimension array [10][8] and [10][20] from my function, but i get an error !! (Segmentation fault).

Please help me !! I need this for my project. Finally i want to print this array and I cant do this because of the error.

Can someone help me fix this and print that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

char **getWords(int level)
{
    if (level == 1)
    {
        char **words = new char *[8];
        strcpy(words[0], "Pakistan");
        strcpy(words[1], "Portugal");
        strcpy(words[2], "Tanzania");
        strcpy(words[3], "Thailand");
        strcpy(words[4], "Zimbabwe");
        strcpy(words[5], "Cameroon");
        strcpy(words[6], "Colombia");
        strcpy(words[7], "Ethiopia");
        strcpy(words[8], "Honduras");
        strcpy(words[9], "Maldives");
        return words;
    }
    //For Hard Level
    else if (level == 2)
    {
        char **words = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * 20);
        strcpy(words[0], "Tajikistan");
        strcpy(words[1], "Uzbekistan");
        strcpy(words[2], "Azerbaijan");
        strcpy(words[3], "Bangladesh");
        strcpy(words[4], "Luxembourg");
        strcpy(words[5], "Madagascar");
        strcpy(words[6], "Mauritania");
        strcpy(words[7], "Montenegro");
        strcpy(words[8], "Mozambique");
        strcpy(words[9], "New Zealand");

        return words;
    }
}

int main()
{
    getWords(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run your code in your debugger and single step through it. Find out what line you get the segfault on. That will help you narrow down the problem. If you don't know how to use your debugger, now is a good time to learn.

Comment: If this is c++, why not use a `std::vector<std::string>`. It will make everything much easier.

Comment: You must allocate buffers for strings before doing `strcpy()` to them.

Comment: returning a local pointer variable from function is nothing less than disaster! `words` is local variable on the stack of `getWords` function. do you know what happens when control return from function to the calling line?

Comment: `char **words =new char*[8];` allocated an array of pointers. Pointers to what, you ask? At the moment, pointers to undefined locations in memory. `strcpy`ing data to unknown locations in memory will have equally unknown results.

Comment: Mixing `malloc` and `new` in the same pointer is a really bad idea. There's no way to tell from a pointer which of `delete` of `free` you need to use to put the memory back again.

Comment: The string "Pakistan" takes 9 bytes, not 8, since a zero is added to terminate it, so strcopy copies 9 bytes.

Comment: strdup makes this a lot simpler

Comment: @user4581301, the OP can always use the flag passed as an argument to choose how to delete. You're right though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing

```
char **words = new char *[10];
```

You are only allocating memory for the pointers, not for the memory blocks where the actual strings are to be stored, you need to allocate memory for that too:

```
char **words = new char *[10]; //space for 10 pointers
        
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    words[i] = new char[10]; // space for 10 characters each line, 8 is not enough
}                            // you need at least 9 because of the ending nul byte

strcpy(words[0], "Pakistan");
strcpy(words[1], "Portugal");
//...
```

In main, assing them to a pointer to pointer and print them as if it was an array of strings:

```
char** words = getWords(1);

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    std::cout << words[i] << std::endl;
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HABAB58PNGa4Tvyo)

The same goes for the second part which uses `malloc`.

```
char **words = (char**)malloc(sizeof *words * 10); //space for 10 pointers

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    words[i] = (char*) malloc(20); //space for 20 characters each line
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0DHMHz9GoA7O50vU)

In a normal situation, when the program doesn't end right away you would have to free the memory:

For memory allocated with `new`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    delete words[i];
}
delete words;
```

For the memory allocated with `malloc`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    free(words[i]);
}
free(words);
```

This can be tricky in your case because you return 2 types of memory allocation deppending on the option you pass as parameter, my advice is that you use that same option to choose how to deallocate the memory.

P.S.: Using C++ containers like `std::vector` and `std::string` would make your job easier, you wouldn't need to handle the memory yourself.

Comment: wow You are AmazinG @anastaciu Tnx !! you Fix My cod

Comment: @kasra, thank you, I'm flattered, I'm gald I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Use of

```
 char **words =new char*[8];
 strcpy(words[0],"Pakistan");
```

is a problem since you have not allocated memory for `words[0]`.

It's analogous to

```
 char* cp; /// Uninitialized pointer
 strcpy(cp,"Pakistan");
```

You'll have to allocate memory for `words[0]`, `words[1]`, etc. before you use them in the call to `strcpy`.

More importantly, change your strategy, and use `std::vector<std::sting>` instead. That makes your code simpler and removes the burden of allocating and dealloating memory from application code.

```
std::vector<std::string> getWords(int level)
{
     std::vector<std::string> words;
     if (level==1)
     {
         words.push_backl("Pakistan");
         // etc.

     
     return words;
}
```

Comment: I await the traditional - "I am not allowed to use string or vector"

Comment: @pm100, Always a possibility when you doing homework :)